# reading a pyspark dataframe with decorator

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, python-decorators, apache-spark-sql

Suppose you have this helper class wrapping various Spark methods:

```
class EasySpark:
    __sc = None
    __spark = None

    def __init__(self, appname, master='local[*]'):
        self.__spark = SparkSession...
        self.__sc = self.__spark.sparkContext

        self.easy_read_csv = self.read_decorator(self.__spark.read.csv)
        self.easy_read_parquet = self.read_decorator(self.__spark.read.parquet) 

    def read_decorator(self, read_func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            path_not_exist_msg = 'Path does not exist'
            table_not_found_msg = 'Table or view not found'
            try:
                result = read_func(*args, **kwargs)
            except AnalysisException as e:
                if path_not_exist_msg in str(e):
                    raise MDSExc.S3PathNotFound(str(e))
                elif table_not_found_msg in str(e):
                    raise MDSExc.TableOrViewNotFound(str(e))
                else:
                    raise e
            return result
        return wrapper
```

The read_decorator is a simply way to decorate the spark reading function in order to handle some useful exceptions (maybe this is not the best way to do that but it is not the main problem).

Let's analyze the following snippet where the first dataframe comes from a source file semicolon-separated while the second one comes from a comma-separated file (the default separator of `spark.read.csv`):

```
es = EasySpark('test_app')
df1 = es.easy_read_csv('path/to/first/source', sep=';')
df2 = es.easy_read_csv('path/to/second/source')
```

In this way the `df1` is correctly read, but the `df2` is (wrongly) read with `sep=';'` despite we have not specified that parameter in the second call! Moreover (to do some experiments) if I wrap in the way described above a `pandas` read function I have no any problem (you can found the reproducible code [here](https://pastecode.xyz/view/890e87c9).

I'm working with Spark Version: 2.2.0 and Python version: 3.6.2 (anaconda 64 bit)

Some help?